# Dynamic Object - Tidy property names?

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, .net-4.0, c#-4.0

I'm using some code to execute a SQL and return a IEnumerable of dynamic objects.  The code is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2009/10/29/using-c-dynamic-to-simplify-ado-net-use.aspx) if you want to see it.

I have a table with a column name such as APPLICATION_NAME;

In my object I have to reference it like so:

```
var results = ReturnResults("Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=rawdb;Data Source=mypc", "SELECT * FROM APPLICATIONS");

string name = results.First().APPLICATION_NAME;
```

Is there a way to make property names resolve to something tidier? ie.

```
string name = results.First().ApplicationName;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some `ToCamelCase()` extensions out there (just [google it](http://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+string+tocamelcase)). But if you would implement it into your dynamic object. How do you know which shiny name you have to take for an ugly column name?

Instead you should rewrite your select statement to return nice names, instead of implementing some algorithm into the dynamic object. How about this statement:

```
SELECT APPLICATION_NAME as 'ApplicationName' FROM APPLICATIONS
```

So it is clear to everyone who reads the sql statement how to access the columns through the dynamic object.

Comment: That was the one thing I did think about, how it would map shiny to ugly!  Your SQL makes perfect sense however but not ideal in my situation.

Comment: The big problem isn't how your dynamic object makes the conversion. The problem is how does the programmer know which shiny name he has to pick for the ugly column name? Due to the fact, that it is a dynamic object he doesn't get any support from the compiler.